# Scala - toList vs. result on ListBuffer?

Tags: scala, listbuffer

The documentation for ListBuffers offer two methods that convert the ListBuffer into a List: `result` and `toList`.

`result` says it produces a collection from the added elements and that the contents are undefined afterward.

`toList` seems to instead make a constant-time lazy copy of the contents of the buffer (and presumably leaves the buffer intact).

If `toList` is constant time, when would we ever prefer `result`?  And also am I understanding this correctly that `toList` will preserve the buffer's contents?

Comment: And if we look at the source (https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L1) we see `def result: List[A] = toList` :)

Comment: @Paul - you should post that as an answer, so the question can be closed.

Comment: I'm not sure it is an answer. It's an implementation artifact. It maybe a future version will decide to do the two differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look [at the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L1) we see

```
def result: List[A] = toList
```

So (at least in the current version of Scala), there's no need to prefer one to the other.